# Is the demon Luci two-dimensional?

Tags: animation, disenchantment

One of the main characters in the latest Matt Groening cartoon is the "personal demon" called Luci, who is supposed to drag princess Bean to sin, darkness and the Dark Side. Not that she needs encouragement...

In universe, other people treat Luci as a "weird talking cat", but one thing makes me wonder - is he two dimensional? We always see Luci from the side, even when he walks towards viewer

[image: Cool kids don't look at explosions]

I don't think we even seen both of his eyes at the same time, yet he has visible eye, no matter what direction his head is pointing

[image]

Is this just the effect of drawing him as plain black (so there is no way to show depth of character) or is he indeed "flat" and always pointing his side to the viewer?

Comment: They are all 2-dimensional. )

Comment: @Verdan but some are more ;)

Comment: Interesting point about never seeing both his eyes - when Luci is first shown in the box you only see a big eye, the same when he possesses Bean in ep. 3.  Maybe he is just the eye and the blackness is just a manifestation.

Comment: Luci does not seem to be drawn in Groening's usual style. As @Yasskier suggests, he is all black, but I think it goes deeper (ha!) than that. He's a demon so he lacks the details and bodily imperfections which define us as human or elf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**His head is, but not his body.**

As can be seen in [studio notes shared on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/1353847031381385/posts/1507207316045355/), Luci’s body is able to move any direction it needs to (including going on all fours with all limbs visible, which clearly demands depth), but his head must only be viewed from the side.

[image: Studio notes on drawing Luci]

[image: Studio notes on drawing Luci]

[image: Studio notes on drawing Luci]

[image: Studio notes on drawing Luci]

[image: Studio notes on drawing Luci]